# How to get urlpattern from django request

Tags: python, django

For example:

```
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.index, name='main-view'),
    path('bio/<username>/', views.bio, name='bio'),
    path('articles/<slug:title>/', views.article, name='article-detail'),
    path('articles/<slug:title>/<int:section>/', views.section, name='article-section'),
    path('weblog/', include('blog.urls')),
    ...
]
```

I want to get the `'articles/<slug:title>/'`string from a request, not the value of title var.

I use Django 1.8.2

Comment: [.path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want just real `path`, you can use `request.path`. [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path)

If you want `<slug:title>` parameter, you just get in your `view` function by `function arguments` like this.

```
def some_view(request, title):
    # do your job.
```

**Edit**

You need this two functions.

```
from django.urls import resolve, get_resolver, URLResolver, URLPattern


def get_view_name_by_path(path):
    result = resolve(path=path)
    return result.view_name


def find_url_pattern_by_name(name):
    if name is None:
        return None

    def deep_find(rs):
        for r in rs.url_patterns:
            if isinstance(r, URLResolver):
                result = deep_find(r)
                if result is not None:
                    return result
            elif isinstance(r, URLPattern):
                if r.name == name:
                    return r.pattern

    return deep_find(get_resolver())
```

You must set `name` on your `url pattern`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('articles/<slug:title>', your_view, name='your_view_name'),
    ...
]
```

Finally you can get your pattern in your view.

```
def your_view(request, title):
    view_name = get_view_name_by_path(request.path)
    pattern = find_url_pattern_by_name(view_name)
    ...
```

Comment: I want "articles/<slug:title>/" string, not the value of <slug:title>.

Comment: raw string of `articles/<slug:title>/`? not `articles/some-title/`?

Comment: raw string of articles/<slug:title>/

Comment: Thanks.  However,it doesn't run in Django1.8. I write a Django 1.8 version: https://gist.github.com/ladder1984/420dfd53c9a59bcd4ddd28293cc06b45

Answer (score 1):

This came up for me today and I figured I’d update the answer with what I found for Django > 4.1:

```
from django.urls import resolve
pattern = resolve(request.path).route
```